# Override MaterialUI MuiCheckbox icons default props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I would like to override MuiCheckbox icons, for instance, the `icon` & `indeterminateIcon` props with custom SVG icons across the whole project.

I am using a custom theme:

```js
import { CustomBlankIcon, CustomIndeterminateIcon } from "./Icons";

const theme = responsiveFontSizes(
  createMuiTheme({
    props: {
      MuiCheckbox: {
          icon: CustomBlankIcon,
          indeterminateIcon: CustomIndeterminateIcon
      }
    },
  })
);
```

However, this isn't working, it's throwing an error:

```
Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined
```

Any ideas on how to override the default icon props inside this theme configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a `node` instead of a function/component name, try

```js
import { CustomBlankIcon, CustomIndeterminateIcon } from "./Icons";

const theme = responsiveFontSizes(
  createMuiTheme({
    props: {
      MuiCheckbox: {
          icon: <CustomBlankIcon />,
          indeterminateIcon: <CustomIndeterminateIcon />
      }
    },
  })
);
```